# tkinter - How to set font for Text?

Tags: python, text, fonts, tkinter, widget

I am trying to find the best font for displaying utf-8 characters in a `tk.Text`.

I let python print all the family names known to tk using this code:

```
print(font.families(root=self.parent))
```

and all the known names for usages using this code:

```
print(font.names(root=self.parent))
```

However the output out the families is a list of fonts, which have names consisting of one or more words. It's easy to set the ones with one word like this:

```
text = tk.Text(master=self.frame)
text.configure(font='helvetica 12')
```

But when I try the same with the font names, which consist of multiple words, I get an error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got <second word of the family name>
```

I can't style it, since it is a tk and not a ttk widget, so unfortunately I cannot do:

```
style.configure('My.TText', fontsize=12, font='<family name with multiple words>')
```

I also tried to simply remove whitespace of the family name like this:

```
text.configure(font='fangsongti')
```

But that causes tkinter to use some fallback font. I checked it entering a name like:

```
text.configure(font='fangsongtisdngfjsbrgkrkjgbkl')
print(text.cget('font'))
```

And this results in printing the exact string I entered as a family name. So it simply accepts everything, except multiple worded names.

I found some fonts, which do look OK, but only at certain sizes and I am not sure if they're available on most systems:

```
# helvetica 12
# gothic 13
# mincho 13
```

How can I set fonts with names consisting of multiple words? If I can't, which font, having a one worded name, is appropriate for displaying utf-8 characters like for example Chinese (but not exclusively!) characters on common font sizes *and* is available on most systems?

Comment: The `font` parameter, if I am not wrong, needs a Font object! So, just create your font object using the `Font` class, and then assign the reference to that `font` field of your widget.

Comment: @nbro: it can also take a tuple.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, I was not sure about that option ;)

Comment: The font parameter can take a font object, the name of a named font, a font descriptor string, or a tuple. The tkFont.Font(font=...) is a great mechanism for "normalizing" different font representations, like descriptors, tuples, font objects, font names, etc.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When specifying fonts in this manner, use a tuple:

```
text.configure(font=("Times New Roman", 12, "bold"))
```

Even better, you can create your own custom font objects and specify the attributes by name. Note: before you can create a font object you must first create a root window.

```
# python 2
# import Tkinter as tk
# from tkFont import Font

# python 3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
...
myFont = Font(family="Times New Roman", size=12)
text.configure(font=myFont)
```

The advantage to creating your own fonts is that you can later change any attribute of the font, and every widget that uses that font will automatically be updated.

```
myFont.configure(size=14)
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan, it worked! I was wrongly assuming, that tk widgets can't use objects of ttk classes, because ttk is newer. The tuple "trick" is also good to know.

Comment: @SashaPachev: thanks for the edit! That bug went unnoticed for a year and a half!

Comment: You seem to be missing the `root` argument to `Font`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: The `Font` class doesn't take a root argument, but I've update my answer to hopefully be more clear that you need to create a root window before creating a font.

Comment: A tuple with just the first two entries also works. Example: `font=("Times New Roman", 12)`

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: yes, it does. It also works with just the first element. Using font objects is still better, though.