# Adding Downloaded Fonts To Tkinter

Tags: python, fonts, tkinter

I want to download an open source font and use it in my Python Tkinter Program.

How can I tell Tkinter to import a font from a directory or by putting the font in the same folder as the program ?

**Note:** 
I have searched for an answer for a while even reading API reference of Tkinter about every font related thing I could find. If there was an obvious answer to this question and I didn't know because maybe I didn't search hard enough or asked the wrong questions I am sorry.

Comment: Will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918073/tkinter-how-to-set-font-for-text) help?

Comment: @AndrewL. Unfortunately It wasn't what I was looking for, I wanted to know If there was a way to import fonts into Tkinter but still thanks !

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993290/truly-custom-font-in-tkinter. It works for me on Windows. I haven't tried to find an equivalent for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on Windows (and I would guess on any platform which supports the **pyglet** module)

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyglet, os

pyglet.font.add_file('myFont.ttf')  # Your TTF file name here

root = tk.Tk()
MyLabel = tk.Label(root,text="test",font=('myFont',25)) 

MyLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why dont you actually use `font=('myfont',25)` to actually not confuse the OP, and also the ttf font file name should be same as the ttf font name for `pyglet` to work properly, or it will not show the font.

Comment: @PSSolanki It doesn't works on Raspberry Pi 4. Can you tell why ?

Comment: @sodmzs1 Hey there, I've no idea how rasp pi works so I'd suggest ask this as a separate question :)

Comment: No it isn't. The question isn't tagged with a specific operating system and this solution doesn't seem to work on Linux at least.  And maybe not on any other operating system.

Comment: Then maybe suggest a solution that works on Linux? @BlackJack I specifically said the answer is only tested on Windows and I no longer work with tk (or windows for that matter.

Comment: It's perfectly okay to say *this* isn't a general solution to the question when it simply isn't. That doesn't mean *I* have to waste time to find one. Because most probably there isn't one unless I or someone else would be willing to develop and test and maintain such a functionality for each platform the Python/Tk  combo is generally working on. „Platform“ here may include different Windows versions and differences in Linux like X vs. Wayland.

Comment: Thanks Captain Obvious for pointing out the literal most obvious thing mentioned within the answer that this is not a general solution. I hadn't come across any cross platform solution so I responded what I had because the OP didn't have a specific requirement. I no longer work with tk/windows and hence can't update the answer. While I totally agree that it is `perfectly okay to` point this out, you didn't need to point that out explicitly when I myself mentioned that in the answer itself in the first line. I see your point, but it felt unnecessary. Cheers!