# Text Widget does not display Unicode Characters

Tags: python, unicode, tkinter

I am working on a regional language text editor, which takes the regional Unicode characters (script that I am using is Gurmukhi and Unicode compatible font is Raavi) from text widget and prints it on the terminal screen.

Now problem arises when I copy and paste some characters strings into the text widget, it get convert into the boxes as shown in the image, but it prints perfect string on terminal window.

Although I have tried `encoding` and `decoding` functionality from `codecs`, but, that too gets in vain.

I cannot find any answer related to Unicode entry mechanism for Text widget in Tkinter.

How we can show perfect unicode string ਸਤਵਿੰਦਰ in text widget?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import *

def retrieve_input(self):
    inputValue = content_text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(inputValue)

root = Tk()
root.call('encoding', 'system', 'utf-8')
customFont = tkFont.Font(family='Raavi', size=17)
root.title("Unicode Handling")
root.geometry('400x200+150+200')
content_text = Text(root, wrap='word', font=customFont)
content_text.configure(font=customFont)
content_text.focus_set()
content_text.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')
scroll_bar = Scrollbar(content_text)
content_text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)
scroll_bar.config(command=content_text.yview)
scroll_bar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
root.bind("<space>", retrieve_input)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is input and output:

[image: Input and Output]

Comment: Are you sure that the "Raavi" font that you're using supports unicode? Using a string isn't the proper way to configure a font.  Perhaps the widget is falling back to a default font that doesn't support your characters.

Comment: I have tried to used the solution given [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918073/tkinter-how-to-set-font-for-text) to handle the Unicode text using the font for the input. As far as my knowledge is concerned Python handle the Unicode text using the codecs, but its encode and decode funtions are not working.

Comment: To display a character, a font has to have a glyph for it. It could be 100% properly encoded or decoded, but if the font doesn't support the character then it will be impossible for the widget to properly display the character. Your first step is to make sure you are using a suitable font.

Comment: @BryanOakley The mentioned fonts are Unicode compatible, still it shows the same behavior. Does Tkinter support Indic scripts?

Answer (score 3):

> How we can show perfect unicode string ਸਤਵਿੰਦਰ in text widget?

Your code should work, assuming you have the correct font installed. I've reduced your code to a more minimal example:

```
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
customFont = tkFont.Font(family='Raavi', size=17)
content_text = Text(root, font=customFont, width=20, height=4)
content_text.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')
content_text.insert("end", 'ਸਤਵਿੰਦਰ')

root.mainloop()
```

On my system this results in the following:

[image: screenshot of tkinter window]

When I print the results of `customFont.actual()` I get the following (I don't have the "Ravii" font installed so tkinter will substitute a fallback font, which may be different on your system):

```
{
    'slant': 'roman', 
    'underline': 0, 
    'size': 17, 
    'family': 'DejaVu Sans', 
    'overstrike': 0, 
    'weight': 'normal'
}
```

To see a list of all of the font families that your installation of tkinter will recognize, run this code:

```
from tkinter import font, Tk

root = Tk()
print(font.families())
```

Comment: I tried to run your given code on my system but It shows the same boxes instead of text. I don't know why?

Comment: I got following result: {'underline': 0, 'weight': 'normal', 'family': 'fixed', 'slant': 'roman', 'size': 17, 'overstrike': 0}

Comment: @programmer_123: that means you aren't properly specifying the font, so tkinter is falling back to a default. It is telling you that in spite of what you requested, what it's actually using is a font family named "fixed".

Comment: Yeah, I got this ('fangsong ti', 'fixed', 'clearlyu alternate glyphs', 'courier 10 pitch', 'open look glyph', 'bitstream charter', 'song ti', 'open look cursor', 'newspaper', 'clearlyu ligature', 'mincho', 'clearlyu devangari extra', 'clearlyu pua', 'clearlyu', 'clean', 'nil', 'clearlyu arabic', 'clearlyu devanagari', 'gothic', 'clearlyu arabic extra') after running `print(font.families())` and it doesn't contain Raavi. How can we insert a font in a family?

Comment: @programmer_123: I can't answer that in a comment.