# print arabic char in python

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class entr:
    def __init__(self):
        frm = tk.Tk()
        frm.title( "Myform" )
        frm.geometry( "600x100" )
        frm.config( bg = "blue" )

        
        self.Var_text1 = StringVar()
        self.entry1 = Entry( frm, justify='right', textvariable=self.Var_text1)
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry1.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda event : self.print_char(event) ) 

        frm.mainloop()

    
    def print_char(self,event):        
        print(event.char)        
    
e=entr()
```

This code prints English letters as "u",
But if I enter an Arabic letter like "ع" it is not printed

Comment: Possibly a locale issue. What version of Python, what operating system, what locale are you running in? Also, you're running on key release, do you actually have individual keys that produce Arabic characters? You may want to check the docs; a composed character might not appear the same way.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45489698/8564999)

Comment: Python Version: 3.10.4 , operating system: windows 10, locale :Saudi Arabia

Comment: and my keyboard is Arabic