# Python tkinter font do not change

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, label

I can't change the font of the Labels.

```
from tkinter import *

nc = Tk()

#LABEL cognome
cognome_l=Label(nc, text="cognome", 
        font=('Ubuntu 20'))
cognome_l.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='E',padx=5, pady=5)

#LABEL cognome
cognome_l=Label(nc, text="cognome", 
        font=('Verdana 20'))
cognome_l.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='E',padx=5, pady=5)


nc.mainloop()
```

The 2 labels should be different but they are the same and the text looks blurry.
How can I fix it?
Thanks

EDIT:
This is what I get:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UcIqr5itZhrTMkspytwbPmLTiQwbhnga/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see a clear difference. Maybe one of the fonts is not installed and the other one is used as a fallback? Try replacing one with  "Times".

Comment: Please take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31918553/13629335

Comment: Both solution doesn't work

Comment: What are the output of `print(Font(font='Ubuntu 20').actual())` and `print(Font(font='Verdana 20').actual())`?  You need to import `Font` class using `from tkinter.font import Font`.

Comment: @acw1668 {'family': 'fixed', 'size': 20, 'weight': 'normal', 'slant': 'roman', 'underline': 0, 'overstrike': 0}

Comment: That means you don't have the two fonts installed, and the fall back font `fixed` is used for both fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using conda environment

Answer (score 0):

You should write `font = ('Verdana', 20)` in spite of `font = ('Verdana 20')`

Comment: It is the same. Same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

```
cognome_l = Label(nc, text="cognome", font="Times 15")
```

You need to specify the property for font like this:

> "`fontname` `fontsize`"
>
> "Courier 14"

**Edited**

I executed your program code using sublime text with python interpreter. I have Verdana font installed on my computer, but not the Ubuntu font.
[image]

The result of Verdana both on Microsoft Word and Python are pretty much the same.
I don't have Ubuntu font and that's why it shows me the default font in python.
So I think maybe you don't have Verdana and Ubuntu fonts installed.

Comment: Same problem. I don't know what is the problem

Comment: What is the name of the font you are using? Because it works for almost every font that I have tried so far.